# django post request data

Tags: python, django, curl, django-models

I have the following POST request

```
curl -v --dump-header --H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name": "John", "age": 27}' "http://localhost:8300/api/v1/create_contact?username=gegham&api_key=3efc6df6023534279d2183a696044a8cfec964a9"
```

Result after I'm printing request.POST is

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'{"name": "John", "age": 27}': [u'']}>
```

but not

```
POST: <QueryDict: {u'name': [u'John'], u'age': [u'27']}>
```

So,I can't use this as dict and get values by keys. 
Why POST data format is difference from usual??

Comment: Django doesn't handle JSON by default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're sending JSON, not form data. Use `request.body` and deserialize it with `json.loads`.

Comment: On a side note: Using postman instead of cURL makes life easier.