# Django POST request from Postman

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, request

I am currently stuck with POST requests in Django. I am trying to send a POST request from an external applications such as smartphones or Postman (not forms) to the rest framework. Get requests work just fine.

I went through many posts but couldn't resolve my issue. I tried to use request.body but always get an empty response. I used print(response.body) to print the output to the console and only get b'' back.

```
class anyClass(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.body)
        return Response({"id": 'anyClass',
                     "data": '1234',
                     })
```

How would I get the data from my request?

My post request sent with Postman:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/v2/Api/anyClass?qrcode=100023&date=2018-11-27&time=08:00:00&value_1=17

Comment: Your POST request should have its data in the body, not in the query string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the response in `request.data`:

```
class anyClass(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        return Response({"id": 'anyClass',
                     "data": '1234',
               })
```

Please see the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) for details.

#### Update

I think you are making wrong kind of usage of postman. Please see the screen shot regarding how to use it:

[image: Postman Usage]

Comment: I tried that. Same issue. I assume this is similar to the problem I have in the moment but my request.body variable is empty.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895105/django-post-request-data

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks for that. I kind of forgot about that!